# problems connecting to VPN server on Raspberry Pi (Debian)

Tags: vpn, pptpd

I have installed pptpd on my Raspberry Pi box (it's Debian-based for those who don't know), it's running but not working properly - I can't connect.

here's interesting log - me trying to connect:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /var/log/syslog | grep pptpd | tail
Aug 21 11:32:24 raspberrypi pptpd[1770]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[1771]
Aug 21 11:32:24 raspberrypi pptpd[1770]: CTRL: Client 77.253.47.194 control connection finished
Aug 21 12:17:21 raspberrypi pptpd[1855]: MGR: PPP binary /usr/sbin/pppd not executable
Aug 21 12:17:27 raspberrypi pptpd[1856]: CTRL: Client 77.253.47.194 control connection started
Aug 21 12:17:27 raspberrypi pptpd[1856]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pptpd[1856]: CTRL: EOF or bad error reading ctrl packet length.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pptpd[1856]: CTRL: couldn't read packet header (exit)
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pptpd[1856]: CTRL: CTRL read failed
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pptpd[1856]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[1857]
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pptpd[1856]: CTRL: Client 77.253.47.194 control connection finished
```

and

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ cat /var/log/syslog | grep ppp | tail  -n 25
Aug 21 11:32:24 raspberrypi pppd[1771]: but I couldn't find any suitable secret (password) for it to use to do so.
Aug 21 11:32:24 raspberrypi pptpd[1770]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=15b84,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Aug 21 12:17:21 raspberrypi pptpd[1855]: MGR: PPP binary /usr/sbin/pppd not executable
Aug 21 12:17:27 raspberrypi pptpd[1856]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Aug 21 12:17:27 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Aug 21 12:17:27 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: Using interface ppp0
Aug 21 12:17:27 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Aug 21 12:17:27 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: peer from calling number 77.253.47.194 authorized
Aug 21 12:17:27 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: kernel does not support PPP filtering
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: ifplugd 0.28 initializing.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: Using interface ppp0/00:00:00:00:00:00
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: Using detection mode: IFF_RUNNING
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: Initialization complete, link beat detected.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: MPPE 128-bit stateless compression enabled
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: Executing '/etc/ifplugd/ifplugd.action ppp0 up'.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: client: Ignoring unknown interface ppp0=ppp0.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: Program executed successfully.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: LCP terminated by peer (MPPE disabled)
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: Modem hangup
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: Connection terminated.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: Connect time 0.1 minutes.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: Sent 3630 bytes, received 6720 bytes.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi pppd[1857]: Exit.
Aug 21 12:17:28 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: Link beat lost.
Aug 21 12:17:29 raspberrypi ifplugd(ppp0)[1882]: Exiting.
```

Can anybody see any clue in these logs?
I don't know much about ppp nor pptp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself encountered the error as well while trying to connect via `PPTP` `VPN` to my Raspberry Pi. After some searching on the error "kernel does not support PPP filtering", [this seems to be an option that needs to be compiled into the kernel](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=3150&p=77338). (See last posts.)

To fix it you would either need to use a different kernel (or different distro+kernel) with the option compiled in to the kernel.
You could also try to [compile your kernel yourself, with the option enabled](http://elinux.org/Rpi_kernel_compilation) (advanced).

Comment: Thanks for help, I thought I'm doing something wrong :-)